# ElasticSearch Bulk Load failure

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning ElasticSearch and trying to do bulk upload using a json file but unfortunately it fails with a parse exception.

Here is my Curl Command Looks like (I am using Postman, I copied this command for reference)

```
curl --location --request PUT '127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk ' \
> --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> --data '@/Users/themis/Downloads/ml-latest-small/movies.json'
```

This is my json file,

```
> `{ "create" : { "_index" : "movies", "_id" : "135569" } } { "id":
> "135569", "title" : "Star Trek Beyond", "year":2016 ,
> "genre":["Action", "Adventure", "Sci-Fi"] } { "create" : { "_index" :
> "movies", "_id" : "122886" } } { "id": "122886", "title" : "Star Wars:
> Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "year":2015 , "genre":["Action",
> "Adventure", "Fantasy", "Sci-Fi", "IMAX"] } { "create" : { "_index" :
> "movies", "_id" : "109487" } } { "id": "109487", "title" :
> "Interstellar", "year":2014 , "genre":["Sci-Fi", "IMAX"] } { "create"
> : { "_index" : "movies", "_id" : "58559" } } { "id": "58559", "title"
> : "Dark Knight, The", "year":2008 , "genre":["Action", "Crime",
> "Drama", "IMAX"] } { "create" : { "_index" : "movies", "_id" : "1924"
> } } { "id": "1924", "title" : "Plan 9 from Outer Space", "year":1959 ,
> "genre":["Horror", "Sci-Fi"] } `
```

Here is the error I got:

```
`{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parse_exception",
                "reason": "unknown key [create] for create index"
            }
        ],
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "unknown key [create] for create index"
    },
    "status": 400
}`
```

Can someone please point me where I am doing mistake and how do I fix that?

Comment: do you get errors if you replace the `create` action with `index`?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. Tested on v8.5.0, worked fine: https://gist.github.com/glenacota/f62f007631f6a019fe1c6db55e9fd300

Comment: I replaced the Create with Index and I still see the error.

Comment: Your solution worked for me as well, but mine is still an error. Anyway I will try to figure it out where it is going wrong.

Comment: +1 @glenacota I was adding an extra space causing the issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call is trying to create an index (i.e. PUT) called `_bulk` (hint: `unknown key [create] for **create index**`)

You need to use POST and not PUT with the [`_bulk` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

```
curl --location --request POST '127.0.0.1:9200/_bulk' \
                           ^^
```

Comment: I tried the above changes and I get this error 

{
    "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/_bulk%20] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, PUT, DELETE, HEAD]",
    "status": 405
}

Comment: You need to remove the additional space after `_bulk` as that space is not part of the endpoint

Comment: +1 
I missed that. Thanks @Val. Now I am able to run successfully.